# What are these blemishes along the grain and how do I correct them?

Tags: finishing

I have a dining table made out of Acacia Wood. The process of preparation was:

1. Mill the table flat
2. Sand the table to 180 Grit
3. Spray Nitrocellulose Lacquer
4. Lightly sand back
5. Spray 4 heavier coats of Nitrocellulose Lacquer

The table felt nice and smooth and was perfect.

However, whenever there are water spots, these are causing white blemishes along the grain, and are raised (you can feel a bump when you run your finger over it).

1. What are these, are what's causing these?
2. How can I avoid this in the future?
3. How do I correct the existing blemishes?

[image]

Comment: Water causes white spots on lacquer finishes. Condensation form drink glasses are the worst leaving rings. I hate to say it, but the best way, is to not let it get wet for any length of time. Wipe up spills immediately. Another coat of lacquer will correct it. Make sure the humidity is low whenever applying lacquer. I have had table tops cloud with high humidity present.

Comment: It's not clear, were these immediately visible when you were done finishing? If so were they not visible *during* finishing? As for your 3, you pretty much know the answer to this already I'm sure. It's impossible to tell for sure (not just from a pic, same in person) but the cause is a mystery, but it sure looks like classic finish "stand off" where a contaminant on the surface (typically glue residue) was not fully removed before finish went on. So any chance this is glue?

Comment: @Graphus they were not visible during nor after finishing. They've only appeared recently (with more use of the table). What's strange is they are following the grain of the wood rather than circular, almost as if they're seeping under the lacquer.

Comment: If the table has seen use and cleaning then water is a good candidate, although the shape of the stains (and that they're localised to one area) makes me very unsure of this diagnosis. And while water may have seeped through tiny pinholes in the lacquer, after four full finishing coats that does seem unlikely.